# How to avoid accdb row size limitation when using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using a DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to import data from Excel to Access.
Everything works fine except some Excel rows that are truncated because there are too much bytes for an Access single row (not field).

I noticed that every field in Access is created as a text(255) while my Excel rows are all no more than 100 characters.

I think that if I manage to import my Excel files creating fields with a default length of 100 chars, I will no longer get truncated data.

Is there a way to set the default text length for Access fields to a specific number?

---

**UPDATE**

Decreasing the default field text size in Access 2010 options seems to be ignored when running `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own import function, and it works:

```
' Import from an Excel with a default field length different from 255 (must be < 255)
Function importFromExcel(fileName As String, fieldLength as integer)
    Dim my_xl_app As Object
    Dim my_xl_worksheet As Object
    Dim my_xl_workbook As Object
    Set my_xl_app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set my_xl_workbook = my_xl_app.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Set s = my_xl_workbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim fieldsNumber As Integer
    Dim recordNumber As Long
    fieldsNumber = s.cells(1, s.Columns.Count).End(1).Column
    recordNumber = s.cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
    tablename = "[" & Replace(GetFilenameFromPath(fileName), ".", "_") & "]"
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DROP TABLE " & tablename
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Creo tabella
    sql = "CREATE TABLE " & tablename & " (F1 TEXT(" & fieldLength & ")) "
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql

    For i = 2 To fieldsNumber
        sql = "ALTER TABLE " & tablename & " ADD COLUMN F" & i & " TEXT(" & fieldLength & ")"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql
    Next



    ' Ora insert
    For i = 1 To recordNumber
        sql = "INSERT INTO " & tablename & " VALUES ("
        For j = 1 To fieldsNumber
            sql = sql & " '" & Replace(s.cells(i, j), "'", "''") & "',"
        Next
        sql = Mid(sql, 1, Len(sql) - 1)
        sql = sql & ")"

    Next

    my_xl_workbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set my_xl_app = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the default text length for Access (2007), click the Office button > "Access Options button" > "Object Designers" (in the pane on the left), then under Table Design, enter 50 in the Default Text Field Size box and click OK.

Comment: As I wrote in the update, the default text size is ignored when I import data with DoCmd.TransferDatasheet

Comment: Seen that just after, sorry.